# Get UserId from Wordpress in custom form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have created custom HTML form for *Wordpress*, after clicking `Submit` button all data are inserted to database.

I need to insert `UserId` too. How can I get It? This form will be accessable only for logged-in users, so I need to get logged user's Id (using Pie Register plugin to login).

My form will be stored like: www.mywpdomain.com/resume/index.html

PHP file to insert data: www.mywpdomain.com/resume/insert.php

I need to use something like: `$UserId = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['UserId']);`

But I'm confused how to achieve It correctly...

Comment: For WordPress you can get user id by using _current_user_id() function.

Comment: @WisdmLabs thank you for suggestion, what should I include to access this function? For now I'm getting an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id() in ....public_html/resume/insert.php on line 13`

Comment: Looks like that I'm missing something to include / define... Note that my form is stored not directly in `public_html`, but in `public_html/resume/`

Comment: Is this insert.php file from plugin? or any theme?

Comment: @WisdmLabs no, It's custom created PHP

Comment: So this function not working there.

Comment: @WisdmLabs so how can I achieve that?

Comment: You have to include first 'wp-includes/user.php' this file from wordpress. And then use get_current_user_id() function.

Comment: Try this method. Include wp_load.php in your insert.php. It will load all wordpress into your php file. And then you can use get_current_user_id() function.  Otherwise you have include both wp_load.php and user.php. wp_load.php is present in wordpress folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105265/discussion-between-wisdmlabs-and-infinity).

Comment: @WisdmLabs thank you, thank worked for me.